# Should constructors have a StoreStore barrier?

Tags: java, c++, java-memory-model, memory-model

Should you put store-store-barriers into constructors?

Here is an example. Assume `global_f = f = r = 0` initially.
One thread A creates an object, assigns to a field, and assigns it to a global variable:

```
class Foo {
    int x;
    void Foo(int x) {
         this.x = x;
    }
}

f = new Foo(42);
global_f = f;
```

Another thread B acquires the reference from the global variable and then reads the field.

```
r = global_f.x;
```

Assuming executions where thread B reads the object reference from thread B, what value can it read from `X` into `r`? Always 42 or not?

I'm interested in the behavior of C++ *and* Java. To my understand of the memory models, `r` is not guaranteed to be 42.

To ensure that the fields of an object are properly initialized, we could put store-store-barriers at the end of constructors in general. This seems to a pitfall in both C++ and Java. At least for Java everything is fine for final fields, isn't it? This is not that critical in practice, because at least on x86 and AMD64 a store-store-barrier is a NOP. However, on other architectures like ARM or POWER it is not.

Comment: C++ only: memory barriers are not (should not be) added automatically, they are the programmers problem.  The following the guidelines apply: _"the only pay for what you use rule"_ and multi threading is too complex for static analysis by the compiler (the compiler sees each compilation unit separately).

Comment: You need to narrow down which language you want to ask about. Java and C++ have differing memory models and language semantics. For one thing, classes are values in C++ and not references. Another is Java's `volatile` is hugely different than that of C++

Comment: I don't see why constructors should be singled out here. The situation is no different from any other method call that sets `x`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there is no guarantee that `r` will be `42` unless you declare the `x` field as `final`.

---

> To ensure that the fields of an object are properly initialized, we could put store-store-barriers at the end of constructors in general. This seems to a pitfall in both C++ and Java.

That is a comment not a question.  However the contrary argument is that putting an implicit barrier at the end of all constructors results in an unnecessary performance hit in various cases; e.g.

- for single-threaded code,
- for multi-threaded code where `f` is not published
- for multi-threaded code where access to `x` is guarded by a synchronized method.

The memory models of Java and C++ are a compromise between simplicity and performance considerations.  If you go too far towards simplicity (i.e. by designing out the so-called pitfalls) multi-threaded code will not give you the kind of speedup that people want / need.